# When are two operators simultaneously diagonalizable?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, stochastic-calculus, diagonalization

I am reading a paper and they have diagonalised both operators in an equation, on a separable Hilbert space, with respect to the same basis. My question is, when can two operators be simultaneously diagonalised? In the paper, one operator is self adjoint and positive definite and the other is bounded and positive.

Thanks.

Context: The problem comes from the generalised Ornstein-Uhlenbeck equation
$$dX_t=-AX_t dt + \sqrt{2a}dB_t$$
where $A$ is a constant self-adjoint positive definite operator on $H$, a separable Hilbert space, $B_t$ is a cylindrical Brownian motion, while $a$ is a constant, positive operator.

The author then diagonalises the system to become $$dX_k(t)=-\lambda_kX_k(t) dt + \sqrt{2a_k}dB_k(t)$$
where $x_k(t)= \langle X_t,\phi_k\rangle$, $A\phi_k=\lambda_k\phi_k$ and $\langle \phi_k,\sqrt{a}\phi_j\rangle=\sqrt{a_k}\delta_{jk}$.

Comment: In linear Algebra if the commutator of both matrices is zero. Maybe this can be generalized to the infinite dimensional case...

Comment: What does it have to do with stochastic calculus? In general, positive operators need not be diagonalizable at all, unless they're compact. You need to supply more details.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that more clear. $A$ can be unbounded and so is not compact in general. It may rely on separability of $H$

Comment: @tomasz you are correct. One needs an assumption like compact and self adjont for simultaneous diagonalisation. Otherwise you can have operators that don't even have eigenvalues.

Comment: @David: Also, when asking about a specific paper, you should link to it. (Not that I'll help you, I have no idea about stochastic calculus, but that would probably make it easier for others...)

Comment: @julien: You are right, I assumed that they are diagonalizable. And then it is a if and only if. So one can expect that this condition has to be fulfilled also in the infinite dimensional case....Of course there will be most probable some additional conditions...but maybe I do not understand, what you mean exactly :)!

Comment: @julien: Let $[,]$ denote the commutator, then we have by definition $[A,B]=AB-BA$ and this is zero if and only if $AB=BA$...where am I wrong?

Comment: @Alex Ah! It took it as the commutant...sorry! Language issue, once more for me. And of course, this is the commutator. And nobody calls the commutant commutator. I don't know what I was thinking...

Comment: @julien: no problem, I thought that this could be a language problem but was not sure...it is as always: The one and only exact language is mathematics :).